# Enumeration on one line

Tags: lists, enumerate

I am trying to have three matrices on one line as

> i) A=(..), ii) B=(..) and ii) C=(..).

I tried `\nopagebreak`, `\noindent` just after item. Instead I always get the Roman numeral on one line, a comma on the next line, etc.
Below is my code

```
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
Determine which of the following matrices are Hermitian

\begin{enumerate}[i)]
\item \begin{displaymath} \noindent A= \begin{pmatrix*} 2 & 2+3i & 4-5i \\
2-3i & 5 & 6+2i \\
4+5i & 6-2i & -7 \\ \end{pmatrix*}
end{displaymath},
\item \begin{displaymath}B= \left [ \begin{array}{rrr}3 & 2-i & 4+i \\[2ex]
2-i & 6 & i \\ [2ex] 4+i & i & 3 \\
\end{array} \right] \end{displaymath},
\item \begin{displaymath}C= \left [ \begin{array}{rrr}4 & -3 & 5 \\[2ex]
-3 & 2 & 1 \\ [2ex] 5 & 1 & -6 \\
\end{array} \right] \end{displaymath}
\end{enumerate}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `enumitem` package that also frees you from manually adding the separators. Note that this package is much more powerful than `paralist` and offers several more bells and whistles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

Determine which of the following matrices are Hermitian\\*[\medskipamount]
\begin{enumerate*}[label=\roman*),itemjoin={,\quad}]
\item $A= \begin{bmatrix*}[r] 
          2    & 2+3i & 4-5i \\
          2-3i & 5    & 6+2i \\
          4+5i & 6-2i &  -7 \\ 
          \end{bmatrix*}$

\item $B= \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
          3 & 2-i & 4+i \\
          2-i & 6 & i \\  
          4+i & i & 3 \\
          \end{bmatrix*}$

\item $C= \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
          4 & -3 & 5 \\
          -3 & 2 & 1 \\
          5 & 1 & -6 \\
          \end{bmatrix*}$
\end{enumerate*}

\bigskip\bigskip

Determine which of the following matrices are Hermitian\\*[\medskipamount]
\begin{enumerate*}[label=\roman*),itemjoin={,\quad}]
\item $A= \begin{bmatrix}
          2    & 2+3i & 4-5i \\
          2-3i & 5    & 6+2i \\
          4+5i & 6-2i &  -7 \\ 
          \end{bmatrix}$

\item $B= \begin{bmatrix}
          3 & 2-i & 4+i \\
          2-i & 6 & i \\  
          4+i & i & 3 \\
          \end{bmatrix}$

\item $C= \begin{bmatrix}
          4 & -3 & 5 \\
          -3 & 2 & 1 \\
          5 & 1 & -6 \\
          \end{bmatrix}$
\end{enumerate*}

\end{document}
```

As you see, the separation between the items is set with the `itemjoin` key.

I added the version with matrices having the default center alignment, which seems much better (except, perhaps, for the third one).

[image]

Comment: Yes this is a very good improvement @egreg, however am getting an error on the line "\begin{enumerate*}[label=\roman*),itemjoin={,\quad}]", giving the error "missing number, treated as zero". I would appreciate help. Further more for my learning what do a) \quad, b) \bigskip do. Note that I remove \quad after each \end{bmatrix}.

Comment: @ZiloreMumba You may have an outdated version of `enumitem`; what TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: I am working on Windows. It seems I have enumitem for 2009-05-25. I do not know how to update it on windows.

Comment: @ZiloreMumba Go to http://miktex.org and install MiKTeX 2.9

Answer (score 5):

You could use the `paralist` package and its `inparaenum` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{mathtools}  % for 'bmatrix*' environment
\usepackage{paralist}   % for 'inparaenum' environment

\begin{document}
Determine which of the following matrices are Hermitian
\bigskip

\begin{inparaenum}[i)]
\item $A= \begin{bmatrix*}[r] 
          2    & 2+3i & 4-5i \\
          2-3i & 5    & 6+2i \\
          4+5i & 6-2i &  -7 \\ 
          \end{bmatrix*}$,\quad
\item $B= \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
          3 & 2-i & 4+i \\
          2-i & 6 & i \\  
          4+i & i & 3 \\
          \end{bmatrix*} $,\quad
\item $C= \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
          4 & -3 & 5 \\
          -3 & 2 & 1 \\
          5 & 1 & -6 \\
          \end{bmatrix*} $
\end{inparaenum}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mico, this does exactly what I wanted. Thanks for your time and effort.